# Why are my rendered images so blurry?

Tags: rendering

*[[image: emphasized text]
why are my rendered images so blurry, when rendering is completely blurry, I try to adjust the setting but not working, who can help me? thanks so much....

Comment: Not sure... The artifacts on the stones in right-bottom corner are interesting... What happens when you render with a single sample? If it wouldn't fix the blurriness (caused e.g. by too big "filter size"), then it would make it easier to spot artifacts perhaps. If sharing the .blend is not an option, then at least make screenshots of scene, render, output settings. And compositor node tree, if used.

Comment: It could be a few things, if you can share the .blend file that would be good, but quick question, do you have depth of field turned on in your camera by chance? Or are you using the compositor?

Comment: yes, I added compositor, and adjust DOF